# User status shows as offline / unknown on corporate network

Tags: microsoft-teams, status, offline

Apologies if this isn't the correct area for this sort of question.

We have an issue with one of our customers, where when they are connected to the corporate network, the user status is shown as offline or unknown. Connecting to any other network shows the status correctly, as does connecting to the corporate VPN. All other functions of Teams work fine on the corporate network, just not the status.

I'm struggling to find out any information as to where this will be failing. I'm assuming traffic to a required endpoint is being blocked / dropped, but I can't see anything obvious and I can't find any info about what traffic and / or endpoint would particularly relate to the status but no other functions.

Has anyone seen anything like this before / got any tips?